# Can I make a Java app borderless using JVM args?

Tags: java, macos, java-11

I am just wondering if it's possible to make an already-compiled Java applet borderless using JVM arguments? A cursory Google brings up a lot of results for Minecraft and configuring OpenGL but it appears that setting is redundant and I'm not sure if that was just for Minecraft.

This is what they did in Minecraft (now deprecated) to hide borders:

```
-Dorg.lwjgl.opengl.Window.undecorated=true
```

The app I'm trying to pull this off with is [Old School RuneScape](https://www.runescape.com/oldschool/download) on macOS Catalina and AdoptOpenJDK JRE 11. I have little understanding of Java and not familiar with Java specifically — only C based languages more broadly. I've looked through a bunch of docs and found a lot of general JVM args for managing garbage collection, cache memory etc so I wondered if there was something to control the border, maybe something like `-DsetUndecorated=true` or setting JFrame arguments somehow editing the config.

Side note: what's the difference between JVMOptions and JVMArguments?

Trying to do this is a workaround for another workaround. The OSRS app of course has a title bar which is blinding when I'm using dark mode for everything else. I added *NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance=NO* to the Info.plist and that worked for a while but suddenly it didn't and now I'm trying to get rid of the title bar completely. I thought it was the JRE and re-installed OSRS and Java, and migrated to AdoptOpenJDK JRE 11.. So if I could either get rid of the title bar or fix the first work around then I'd be very grateful.

Thanks for your help

Comment: The answer greatly depends on what library you are using for creating you application: Swing, JavaFX, OpenGL (lwgl), etc. If using OpenGL, you mentioned the way. For most other sources, you need to catch the argument in code

Comment: Note that support for applets was dropped in Java 9.  So I am guessing that what you are running is not really an applet.

Comment: Note also that there is a support link on that download page.  You should probably contact them ... since this is not really a programming question.

Comment: *"what's the difference between JVMOptions and JVMArguments?"* - Depends on the context.  Possibly none.

Comment: @Maxzeroedge, appears to use AWT